# Formik Yup Validation of array of things

Tags: reactjs, formik, yup

Here's the schema for my data. It includes a few top-level properties but also some nested inputs that are part both a collection `things`, and an object `thing2`. An example of the input name for the first input of the second item in the `things` array is: `things[0].inputs[1].value`. Formik seems to be attaching the values via the names correctly but the validation doesn't seem to work. Any idea where I'm going wrong?

```
const schema = {
    name: "", // string - required
    feed_id: "", //string - required
    things: [
      {
        inputs: [
          // zero, one, or more of the following
          // They all require a value, but it can really be any type, 
          {
            name: "InputName",
            value: "StringInput" // String - required
          },
          {
            name: "InputName",
            value: true // boolean - required
          },
          {
            name: "InputName",
            value: 5 // number - required
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    thingB: {
      inputs: [
        // zero, one, or more of the following
          {
            name: "InputName",
            value: "StringInput" // String - required
          },
          {
            name: "InputName",
            value: true // boolean - required
          },
          {
            name: "InputName",
            value: 5 // number - required
          }
      ]
    }
  };
```

And here's my attempt at a YUP validation for it

```
  const inputValidationSchema = yup.array().of(
    yup.object().shape({
      value: yup
        .mixed()
        .required()
    })
  );

  const validationSchema = yup.object().shape({
    name: yup.string().required(),
    feed_id: yup.string().required(),
    config: yup.object().shape({
      things: yup
        .array()
        .of(yup.object().shape({ inputs: inputValidationSchema })),
      thingB: yup.mixed().oneOf([
        yup.object().shape({
          inputs: inputValidationSchema
        }),
        null
      ])
    })
  });
```

It doesn't seem to work and properly attach the errors to the form.

Comment: Your validation schema seems correct. Do you really pass `things[0].inputs[1].value` to a Formik field? If it's true and you pass it instead of `config.things[0].inputs[1].value` then you have probably passed to wide schema to the Formik than it expects. I think in this case you should pass only `config` part of you validationSchema like `yup.object().shape({ things ...etc})`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you Create a Formik YUP Schema with Dynamic Field Names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60307058/how-do-you-create-a-formik-yup-schema-with-dynamic-field-names)