# How do you Create a Formik YUP Schema with Dynamic Field Names?

Tags: typescript, formik, yup

How do you create a YUP schema with dynamic dot notation field names?  The below schema is not valid.  How would I iterate through Costs.0.item, Costs.1.item, Costs.2.item AND Costs.0.amount, Costs.1.amount, Costs.2.amount dynamically?  Any help is appreciated!

```
const IpSchema = Yup.object().shape({

        Project_Title: Yup.string()
            .min(2, 'Too Short!')
            .max(255, 'Too Long!')
            .required('Required'),
        Costs.0.item: Yup.string()
            .min(2, 'Too Short!')
            .max(255, 'Too Long!')
            .required('Required'),
        Costs.1.item: Yup.string()
            .min(2, 'Too Short!')
            .max(255, 'Too Long!')
            .required('Required'),
        Costs.2.item: Yup.string()
            .min(2, 'Too Short!')
            .max(255, 'Too Long!')
            .required('Required'),
        Costs.0.amount: Yup.string()
            .min(2, 'Too Short!')
            .max(255, 'Too Long!')
            .required('Required'),
        Costs.1.amount: Yup.string()
            .min(2, 'Too Short!')
            .max(255, 'Too Long!')
            .required('Required'),
        Costs.2.amount: Yup.string()
            .min(2, 'Too Short!')
            .max(255, 'Too Long!')
            .required('Required'),

    });
```

Comment: Are expecting to have an arbitrary number of `Costs`?

Comment: Yes, there could be 30+ Costs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use `YUP` with `formik` you can check [this](https://jaredpalmer.com/formik/docs/api/fieldarray#fieldarray-validation-gotchas). On docs provided example. And otherwhise according [docs](https://github.com/jquense/yup#array) you can do it like this:

```
const IpSchema = Yup.object().shape({
  Project_Title: Yup.string()
                    .min(2, 'Too Short!')
                    .max(255, 'Too Long!')
                    .required('Required'),
  Costs: Yup.array().of(
              Yup.object()
                    .shape({
                      item: Yup.string()
                        .min(2, 'Too Short!')
                        .max(255, 'Too Long!')
                        .required('Required'),
                      amount: Yup.string()
                        .min(2, 'Too Short!')
                        .max(255, 'Too Long!')
                        .required('Required')
                    })
                ),
});
```

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response.  This solution works for me - thank you!

Comment: @TerryDoll Can you help me out? I am unable to show the message in the UI as it is coming as array.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `yup.array` in that case, i.e.:

```js
const IpSchema = Yup.object().shape({
  Project_Title: Yup.string()
                    .min(2, 'Too Short!')
                    .max(255, 'Too Long!')
                    .required('Required'),
  Costs: Yup.array().of(
    Yup.object({
      item: Yup.string()
               .min(2, 'Too Short!')
               .max(255, 'Too Long!')
               .required('Required')
      amount: Yup.string()
                 .min(2, 'Too Short!')
                 .max(255, 'Too Long!')
                 .required('Required')
    })
  ),
});
```

Comment: @Muhammad Ali I am getting the error but it is not showing in the UI. What can I do for that?